# Retaining constraints and default values of a layer in QGIS when merging with the same layer with data inputted in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I'm using QGIS and QField for data gathering of poles and lines.
I'm using constraints and default values to come up with the desired output needed for my reports.

Is there a way to retain the constraints and default values in QGIS when merging with the same file/layer from QField?

Comment: just to clarify: you prepare your layer for QField in QGIS, export that project to your tablet, collect data and then you want that collected data back in QGIS. At the same time, you added poles/lines in QGIS and now you want to merge the data collected with QField and the data added in QGIS?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the scenario.

Comment: so the way to go for the future would be to use QField Sync and mark these tables for Offline synchronisation - this has the effect, only changed data entries will be submitted to your main Database (the one in QGIS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy that data from your tablet (including the Project_qfield.qmz) to a folder on your computer and open that Project_qfield.qmz and the QGIS project in seperate instances of QGIS. Then select all that entries you added in QField from the attribute table, and copy and paste them into the "Main Project" (have your table where you insert the data in edit mode).

Comment: It works! Thank you!